# How to add element to Mapbasic Array?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

Code:

```
 Dim name_array() As String
 Redim name_array(10)
```

How to add value to the array? I know we can add value by specifying index like   name_array(i) = "some_value"

But I don't want to specify any index *i*. Instead is it possible to Add a value to array to last index used.

eg.  *If i have added to i=5 Will I be able to add to 6th index without specifying index?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't be that hard to write your own procedure for doing that:

```
Sub ARRAddItem(arrValues() As String, ByVal sNewValue As String)

Dim nItem As Integer

    nItem = Ubound(arrValues) + 1
    Redim arrValues(nItem)

    arrValues(nItem) = sNewValue

End Sub
```

Note that it will resize the array with one and insert the value at this index

Comment: Why not use function ?

Comment: If you want to use a procedure or a function would depend on the "feedback" from the function you would like. If you would like to know at what index the value was added, you could use a function. Or you could use a function that just gives you a "true" back if the value was added. A function in MapBasic can not return an array, if that was what you were looking for

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible unless you write your own function, which keeps track of the index internally. MapBasic simply doesn't offer any modern container classes. Or any classes for that matter.